# How to add priority fee to NFT printNewEdition

Tags: solana-program, web3.js

I am using Transaction Builder to prepend priority fee but getting error when trying to sign and confirm the transaction "Already Initialized"

```
const editionTx = await metaplex
  .nfts()
  .builders()
  .printNewEdition(editionParams, {
    commitment: "finalized",
  });

// prepend priority fee
editionTx.prepend({
  instruction: ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({
    microLamports: 600000,
  }),
  signers: [],
});


// get Latest blockhash
const { recentBlockhash } = await getRecentBlockHash(SOLANA_CONNECTION);

const response = await sendAndConfirm(
  editionTx,
  metaplex,
  recentBlockhash
)
```